# php - how do i check day value from the given two dates?

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I dont know if this question already asked before.

Actually i have two date:

```
$date1 = $DATABASE_VALUE;

$day1 = date('d', strtotime($date1)); // $date1 is my database value

$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$day2 = date('d', strtotime($date2)); // $date2 current date
```

and I need to Check this:

```
if($day1 <= $day2) {
   ...
}
```

It is working if `$date1` has a date value (Like - `2014-06-12 10:20:50`) and i have set a default value which is

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

so when `$date1` is not  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (could be `2014-06-12 10:20:50`) then :

```
$date1 = "2014-06-12 10:20:50"; // database value

$day1 = date('d', strtotime($date1)); 

echo $day1; // returns 12 (which is correct)
```

But if `$date1` is  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` then

```
$day1 returns 01
```

**WHY?**

If its a behavior of `strtotime()` (Not Sure About That).

Then tell me What should i do if date comes `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ?

Please help..

Comment: First, date('d',strtotime(...)) : give you only the day (1...31). So you're comparing 12 to 1, no matter month or year. Next, strtotime refers to unix timestamp, based on 01/01/1970. So when you do : strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00'), it means : 1970-01-01, that's why you have "01" instead of "00" (you ask for a day, day 0 does not exists !). You can use http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add extra condition to your `if` statement which checks if timestamp of `$date1` is different from `0` (`false`).
Somehow like this:

```
$date1 = $DATABASE_VALUE;
$day1 = date('d', $t1 = strtotime($date1)); // $date1 is my database value
$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$day2 = date('d', strtotime($date2)); // $date2 current date

if($t1 && $day1 <= $day2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with some condition, like below:

```
$date1 = $DATABASE_VALUE;

if('0000-00-00 00:00:00' != $date1) {
    $day1 = date('d', strtotime($date1)); // $date1 is my database value
} else {
    $day1 = 0;
}

$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$day2 = date('d', strtotime($date2)); // $date2 current date
```

UPDATE:

```
if(!empty(strtotime($date1))) {
    $day1 = date('d', strtotime($date1)); // $date1 is my database value
} else {
    $day1 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right.. i did something like that before but i dont want to through with `if('0000-00-00 00:00:00' != $date1) {`.

Comment: I added some more, so you can check the same :)

Comment: check @hindmost answer. you are doing very same. but you are doing some extra work. BTW your answer is also working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just compare time after converting:

```
$time1 = strtotime($date1);
if($time1 < time()) {
    //@TODO
}
```

Comment: I want only `day` value not complete `date` with `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Databases can easily return the date that you stored with just the day. i dont know which database you have With Mysql you can use date_format:

```
select date_format(now(), '%d') as DAY; -> 12
```

This in PHP its a simple integer comparison.